# Python CSV file UTF-16 to UTF-8 print error

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, cjk, utf-16

There is a number of topics on this problem around the web, but I can not seem to find the answer for my specific case.

I have a CSV file. I am not sure what was was done to it, but when I try to open it, I get:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

Here is a full `Traceback`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "keywords.py", line 31, in <module>
    main()
  File "keywords.py", line 28, in main
    get_csv(file_full_path)
  File "keywords.py", line 19, in get_csv
    for row in reader:
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u5a07' in position 10:    ordinal    not in range(128)
```

With the help of Stack Overflow, I got it open with:

`reader = csv.reader(codecs.open(file_full_path, 'rU', 'UTF-16'), delimiter='\t', quotechar='"')`

Now the problem is that when I am reading the file:

```
def get_csv(file_full_path):
    import csv, codecs
    reader = csv.reader(codecs.open(file_full_path, 'rU', 'UTF-16'), delimiter='\t', quotechar='"')
    for row in reader:
        print row
```

I get stuck on Asian symbols:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u5a07' in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)

I have tried `decode`, 'encode', `unicode()` on the string containing that character, but it does not seem help.

```
for row in reader:
    #decoded_row = [element_s.decode('UTF-8') for element_s in row]
    #print decoded_row
    encoded_row = [element_s.encode('UTF-8') for element_s in row]
    print encoded_row
```

At this point I do not really understand why. If I

```
>>> print u'\u5a07'
娇
```

or

```
>>> print '娇'
娇
```

it works. Also in terminal, it also works. I have checked The default encoding on terminal and Python shell, it is UTF-8 everywhere. And it prints that symbol easily. I assume that it has something to do with me opening file with `codecs` using UTF-16.

I am not sure where to go from here. Could anyone help out?

Comment: Please show us the *full* traceback of your exception, as well as the relevant section of code.

Comment: You should also read the [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) to understand when and where Python might automatically try to *encode* unicode.

Comment: From the `csv` module documentation: *This version of the csv module doesn’t support Unicode input. Also, there are currently some issues regarding ASCII NUL characters. Accordingly, all input should be UTF-8 or printable ASCII to be safe*.

Comment: Cheers for a quick reply. I have added a full traceback.

Comment: Ok. So the problem is in csv parsing then. I will try this, might help. github.com/jdunck/python-unicodecsv

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `csv` module *can not* handle Unicode input. It says so specifically on its [documentation page](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html):

> **Note:** This version of the `csv` module doesn’t support Unicode input. Also, there are currently some issues regarding ASCII NUL characters. Accordingly, all input should be UTF-8 or printable ASCII to be safe;

You need to convert your CSV file to UTF-8 so that the module can deal with it:

```
with codecs.open(file_full_path, 'rU', 'UTF-16') as infile:
    with open(file_full_path + '.utf8', 'wb') as outfile:
        for line in infile:
            outfile.write(line.encode('utf8'))
```

Alternatively, you can use the command-line utility [`iconv`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv) to convert the file for you.

Then use that re-coded file to read your data:

```
 reader = csv.reader(open(file_full_path + '.utf8', 'rb'), delimiter='\t', quotechar='"')
 for row in reader:
     print [c.decode('utf8') for c in row]
```

Note that the columns then need decoding to unicode manually.

Comment: worked like a charm ! not only it solved the problem, it also widened my understanding of coding in python. Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

Encode errors is what you get when you try to convert unicode characters to 8-bit sequences. So your first error is not an error get when actually *reading* the file, but a bit later.

You probably get this error because the Python 2 CSV module expects the files to be in binary mode, while you opened it so it returns unicode strings.

Change your opening to this:

```
reader = csv.reader(open(file_full_path, 'rb'), delimiter='\t', quotechar='"')
```

And you should be fine. Or even better:

```
with open(file_full_path, 'rb') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter='\t', quotechar='"')
    # CVS handling here.
```

However, you can't use UTF-16 (or UTF-32), as the separation characters are two-byte characters in UTF-16, and it will not handle this correctly, so you will need to convert it to UTF-8 first.

Comment: No, this won't work because the file is not UTF-8 or ASCII. The `csv` module *cannot handle* UTF-16 input. It has no idea how to work with the 2 bytes per character. In fact, the OP already stated they tried to open the CSV file the way you suggest here. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Ah, the penny just dropped. Yeah, it will truncate each value incorrectly. I can't see that he stated that he tried opening it like this.