# open file with csv.reader in utf-8

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8

i try to open a file in utf-8 and step trough the file with the csv.reader:

```
    with codecs.open(sap_file, "rb", "utf-8") as in_file:
        #self.logger.debug("open")
        self.reader = csv.reader(in_file,delimiter=";")
        for row in self.reader:
            self.pnrs[(row[1])]={}
        for rows in self.reader:
            self.pnrs[rows[1]][rows[3]]=rows[4]
```

But here is my traceback:

```
for row in self.reader:
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 38:  ordinal not in range(128)
```

Somebody here with some tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are opening the file in the wrong way, try `open(sap_file, "rb")` instead of `codecs.open(sap_file, "rb", "utf-8")`.

Also read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13875566/python-csv-file-utf-16-to-utf-8-print-error?rq=1).